# Is it true that the Blender User should name particle cache files differently across Scenes to preserve the info?

Tags: particles, cache

Does using multiple scenes in a Blender file increase the chances for cache file conflict and mistaken deletion?

Are there any tips to understand the interface of filenames for the cache with Particles?  After making exploratory clicks I had to explicitly specify the cache file directory, otherwise the panel stated there was no data to read. (relative directory style) (extra work).  Next the interface stated point counts (worse).  After more clicking the interface stated frame counts (better)

Next the render is correct.  Yet the 3D Viewport is not correct, not expected and out of synchronization.  Some of the behaviour makes one start being superstitious and perhaps restart Blender.